# CXF webservice client ObjectFactory

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, wsdl2java

When I use wsdl2java.bat using apache-cxf, it create a class named `ObjectFactory.java` and some wrapper classes which are used in `ObjectFactory.java`class.
I have two questions to ask:

1. What is usage of this class?
2. Is there any way to circumvent generate of these classes?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's nothing invented by CXF but JAXB.